# PHP select value not saving to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, enums

Cannot figure out why the below will save fine on my local test server, but not on my hosted. The dollar sign is the only value that will save on my hosted.  All save fine on local.

For both I have
"`enum('$', '&euro;', '&yen;', '&pound;')`" for the type with utf8_unicode_ci collation.

```
<select name="user_currency" id="user_currency">
    <option value="$" <?php echo ($user_currency == '$'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>$ - Dollar</option>  
    <option value="&euro;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&euro;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&euro; - Euro</option>                      
    <option value="&yen;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&yen;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&yen; - Yen</option>                 
    <option value="&pound;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&pound;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&pound; - Pound</option>               
</select>
```

---

The query:

```
    $query = "UPDATE users as us SET user_currency = ".$db->prep($_POST['user_currency'])." WHERE us.user_id = '{$user_id}'";
```

---

The prep function

```
function prep($value,$strip_tags = 1){ 
       // Stripslashes
       if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $value = stripslashes($value);
       }
       // Quote if not integer
       if (!is_numeric($value) || $value[0] == '0') {
           $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
       }           
      if($strip_tags){
            $value = DB::strip_html_tags($value);
       }else{
            $value = DB::strip_html_tags($value,0);
       }           
       return $value;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where's the insert query?

Comment: How could it saved to your local test server ?

Comment: I'm using XAMMP for my local test server.

Comment: not sure what is the question?

Comment: why would it save to my local and not my hosted?  If the code is identical, what could be causing it.

Comment: please clarify with full code, mysql query, form action, etc

Comment: Sad to see people down vote this.  And for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try changing this part:

```
<select name="user_currency" id="user_currency">
    <option value="$" <?php echo ($user_currency == '$'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>$ - Dollar</option>  
    <option value="&euro;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&euro;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&euro; - Euro</option>                      
    <option value="&yen;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&yen;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&yen; - Yen</option>                 
    <option value="&pound;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&pound;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&pound; - Pound</option>               
</select>
```

to be:

```
<select name="user_currency" id="user_currency">
    <option value="$" <?php echo ($user_currency == '$'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>$ - Dollar</option>  
    <option value="&amp;euro;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&euro;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&euro; - Euro</option>                      
    <option value="&amp;yen;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&yen;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&yen; - Yen</option>                 
    <option value="&amp;pound;" <?php echo ($user_currency == '&pound;'?'selected="selected"':'');?>>&pound; - Pound</option>               
</select>
```

Otherwise the browser is going to send the actual currency characters which don't match your stated enums. [Edit] This is because your enums are HTML entities.  Might I suggest switching internally to using currency codes like JPY, USD, etc.?

[Clarification edit: The ISO currency codes are a lot easier to move around, and 3rd-party APIs are more likely to use them if you ever decide to draw upon some of the currency-related resources out there.  As to why it worked locally and not on the external server... could be a PHP version difference in entity handling if you're using any of the entity functions on user input.  If that's the case, all the more reason to use ISO currency codes.]